How to associate Java EE models with the logged-in user using Keycloak Adapter
I have a Java EE application that uses the Keycloak Adapter for authentication. The adapter handles the login process and redirects the authenticated user with a JWT token. The issue I'm facing is associating my application models (like Post, Comment, etc.) with the logged-in user. Since Keycloak manages the users, there is no direct user table in my database. How can I associate these models with the Keycloak user?
I can extract the sub (user ID) from the Keycloak JWT token, but I need a way to look up or create a corresponding user in my database and associate it with the relevant entities. How can this be done without having to manage user authentication separately in my application?
KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext> kp = (KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext>) principal;
KeycloakSecurityContext keycloakSecurityContext = kp.getKeycloakSecurityContext();
AccessToken token = keycloakSecurityContext.getToken();
String username = token.getPreferredUsername();
String email = token.getEmail();
String surname = token.getFamilyName();
String name = token.getGivenName();
String nif = (String) token.getOtherClaims().get("nif");


Why don't you just create a User Storage SPI to interface directly with your database?

@CardinalSystem
I’ve considered using an event listener in Keycloak to sync user events (like registrations and updates) with our database. It’s a valid, simpler option before fully committing to a User Storage SPI, what do you think?

I think that I don't know enough about Keycloak to give any further input :-)

@CardinalSystem, no worries, anyway thanks for answering :p
